# Does a character benefit from both racial and class weapon proficiencies?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

If I play a dwarf wizard, does he have both Wizard weapon proficiencies (e.g. daggers) as well as Dwarf weapon proficiencies (e.g. battleaxes)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes, the Dwarf Gains Proficiency with Dwarf Weapons and Wizard Weapons.

Unless traded for an alternate racial trait, the dwarf gains the Weapon Familiarity offense racial trait, which reads

> **Weapon Familiarity:** Dwarves are proficient with battleaxes, heavy picks, and warhammers, and treat any weapon with the word “dwarven” in its name as a martial weapon.

This doesn't alter or replace the weapon proficiencies granted from taking a level in the wizard class. As such the typical dwarf wizard is proficient with the battleaxe, heavy pick, and warhammer because the character's a dwarf and the club, dagger, heavy crossbow, light crossbow, and quarterstaff if he's a typical [wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Weapon-and-Armor-Proficiency). The typical wizard doesn't gain proficiency with any martial weapons, so the latter part of the Weapon Familiarity racial trait is unaffected.